# Viewing answers in StackExchange for Emacs

Tags: sx.el

[StackExchange for Emacs](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el) is exactly what it sounds like.

After authenticating and loading `sx-tab-topvoted emacs`, I see a buffer of question headings.

```
  46   3 Are there any advantages to using ~/.emacs.d/init.el instead of ~/.emacs?
         30d ago [init-file] 
  37   6 How can I use Emacs to edit questions, answers, and comments here? 
         4d ago [major-mode] [integration] 
  34   4 What are the practical differences between the various Emacs Package Repositories?
         32d ago [package] [package-repositories]
  ...
```

That one looks interesting. I move point over the second question and press `RET` to `View question`.

Once I do that, I can see the question header, but not the question body or any of the answers.

Full contents of buffer:

```
How can I use Emacs to edit questions, answers, and comments here?
Author:   daveloyall
Asked on: 12:15 - 21 Oct (edited 14d ago by Malabarba)
Score:    37
Tags:     [major-mode] [integration]
________________________________________________________________________________
```

Is this a known issue or do I have a problem with my configuration? What can I do to see the full contents?

Comment: What version of emacs are you running and how did you install `sx.el`? There is a known problem when installing on 24.4 via `package.el`.

Comment: I don't know sx.el, but do you know StackOverflowSearch(sos.el) ? you type a query and have all the results in an org-mode buffer ! https://github.com/omouse/emacs-sos

Comment: @Ehvince That is pretty nifty :) We're hoping to incorporate search in the coming weeks, but things are hectic :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in your version of `sx`. It has since been fixed.

[Issue report on GitHub](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/issues/164#issuecomment-67526423)

Comment: Specifically commit [`641bef`](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/commit/641beffbc3ce72b4e1b9b6bbb79880ba795fdf72)

Comment: @SeanAllred: as an aside, is `sx` now far enough along to be useable day-to-day?

Comment: @Dan Day-to-day: absolutely.  The only major hindrance right now is tagging new questions, but I haven't had time to finish the branch that would really allow that recently.  See [#137](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/issues/137).  For commenting and answering questions, you should be golden :)

Comment: @Dan I'd say the lack of an inbox is the only real issue right now. Tagging new questions, as Sean mentioned, is a bit annoying because there's no completion yet.